# How can I add events to a wrapped class in C#?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, event-handling, directsound

I am using the `DirectSound` framework and `SecondaryBuffer` objects. I am wrapping the `SecondaryBuffer` object in another class because I have some other values I want to associate with my `SecondaryBuffer`.

After playing a sound, I would like to dispose of the `SecondaryBuffer`, however, the only way to check to see if it is done playing is to check it's Status.

I would like to create an `event` that can be called when the Status of my `SecondaryBuffer` is the correct value.

Here is the snippet that contains my wrapped class.

```
public class WrappedBuffer
{
    public SecondaryBuffer Buffer { get; set; }
    //other variables here

    public WrappedBuffer(SecondaryBuffer buffer, ... and more)
    {
        this.Buffer = buffer;            
    }
}
```

Without events, I have to utilize a `Timer` and check the status like this;

```
if (!Buffer.Status.Playing)
{
     Buffer.Dispose();
}
```

Is there anyway that I can use `events` to call the Dispose() method of the SecondaryBuffer object without having to recheck the Status with a `Timer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no magic here; if the type doesn't already expose an event then you will have to poll until the state changes.  That's how many events are implemented anyway.  At some point you just have to watch for a change if the change is not occurring via one of your methods (in which case you would just fire the event when the value was set/changed).

Comment: If there is no magic, what is the best way to check for these changes? Is a Timer the best way to continually poll?

Comment: @Arnaud : They are other ways to do it. I could create another thread and use a while(true) { Thread.Sleep(1) //check value } loop.

Comment: You could but the timer will manage all that stuff for you. Treatments are optimized with a timer. My politic : "Write less, do more"

Comment: Yes, it's not the only way as Kyle pointed out, but it's the way I would go as it keeps things simple.